# No update of docker container files based on local changes when using Docker-compose volumes

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, volumes

When I make a change to my local file (express-server.js) I'm not seeing notification of the change in the docker-compose terminal. This would imply there is no update to the docker container files occurring. (the 'check' string printed at the bottom of the terminal output is from a `console.log('check')` call but if I change the string argument for this locally and then save I don't see the new string output in terminal.
(It's windows 7 using docker toolbox with oracle virtual toolbox)

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:10.16.3

WORKDIR /usr/src/

COPY ./ ./

RUN npm install

CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  facerecognitionbrain-api:
    container_name: backend
    build: ./
    command: bash -c "ls && npm start"
    working_dir: /usr/src/
    environment:
      POSTGRES_URI: postgres://sally:secret@postgres:5432/facerecognitionbrain-docker
    links: 
      - postgres
    ports:
      - "3008:3008"
    volumes:
      - ./:/usr/src/facerecognitionbrain-api
  postgres:
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: sally
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: secret
      POSTGRES_DB: facerecognitionbrain-docker
      POSTGRES_HOST: postgres
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
```

terminal output after `docker-compose up --build`

```
D:\Dropbox\general\dev\web\projects\43 - face recognition\facerecognitionbrain-api>docker-compose up --build
Creating network "facerecognitionbrain-api_default" with the default driver
Building facerecognitionbrain-api
Step 1/5 : FROM node:10.16.3
 ---> 636ef87129d6
Step 2/5 : WORKDIR /usr/src/
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 3566e0441ff1
Step 3/5 : COPY ./ ./
 ---> 2e23c8e63b06
Step 4/5 : RUN npm install
 ---> Running in 5dd3a7c621a6
npm WARN facerecognitionbrain-api@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN facerecognitionbrain-api@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

audited 3489 packages in 7.482s
found 0 vulnerabilities

Removing intermediate container 5dd3a7c621a6
 ---> e82ecc7a13f6
Step 5/5 : CMD ["/bin/bash"]
 ---> Running in b2abce6baa46
Removing intermediate container b2abce6baa46
 ---> f777b1b42dff

Successfully built f777b1b42dff
Successfully tagged facerecognitionbrain-api_facerecognitionbrain-api:latest
Creating facerecognitionbrain-api_postgres_1 ... done
Creating backend                             ... done
Attaching to facerecognitionbrain-api_postgres_1, backend
postgres_1                  | The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".
postgres_1                  | This user must also own the server process.
postgres_1                  |
postgres_1                  | The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.utf8".
postgres_1                  | The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
postgres_1                  | The default text search configuration will be set to "english".
postgres_1                  |
postgres_1                  | Data page checksums are disabled.
postgres_1                  |
postgres_1                  | fixing permissions on existing directory /var/lib/postgresql/data ... ok
postgres_1                  | creating subdirectories ... ok
postgres_1                  | selecting dynamic shared memory implementation ... posix
postgres_1                  | selecting default max_connections ... 100
postgres_1                  | selecting default shared_buffers ... 128MB
postgres_1                  | selecting default time zone ... Etc/UTC
postgres_1                  | creating configuration files ... ok
postgres_1                  | running bootstrap script ... ok
backend                     | Dockerfile
backend                     | config.js
backend                     | controllers
backend                     | docker-compose.yml
backend                     | express-server.js
backend                     | facerecognitionbrain-api
backend                     | hidden
backend                     | middleware
backend                     | node_modules
backend                     | package-lock.json
backend                     | package.json
postgres_1                  | performing post-bootstrap initialization ... ok
backend                     |
backend                     | > facerecognitionbrain-api@1.0.0 start /usr/src
backend                     | > nodemon express-server.js
backend                     |
backend                     | [nodemon] 1.18.3
backend                     | [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
backend                     | [nodemon] watching: *.*
postgres_1                  | syncing data to disk ... ok
postgres_1                  |
postgres_1                  | initdb: warning: enabling "trust" authentication for local connections
postgres_1                  | You can change this by editing pg_hba.conf or using the option -A, or
postgres_1                  | --auth-local and --auth-host, the next time you run initdb.
postgres_1                  |
postgres_1                  | Success. You can now start the database server using:
postgres_1                  |
postgres_1                  |     pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgresql/data -l logfile start
postgres_1                  |
postgres_1                  | waiting for server to start....2019-11-05 10:45:25.106 UTC [40] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 12.0 (Debian 12.0-2.pgdg100+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0, 64-bit
postgres_1                  | 2019-11-05 10:45:25.108 UTC [40] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
postgres_1                  | 2019-11-05 10:45:25.138 UTC [41] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2019-11-05 10:45:24 UTC
postgres_1                  | 2019-11-05 10:45:25.144 UTC [40] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
postgres_1                  |  done
postgres_1                  | server started
postgres_1                  | CREATE DATABASE
postgres_1                  |
postgres_1                  |
postgres_1                  | /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: ignoring /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*
postgres_1                  |
postgres_1                  | 2019-11-05 10:45:25.571 UTC [40] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
postgres_1                  | waiting for server to shut down...2019-11-05 10:45:25.572 UTC [40] LOG:  aborting any active transactions
postgres_1                  | 2019-11-05 10:45:25.581 UTC [40] LOG:  background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 47) exited with exit code 1
postgres_1                  | 2019-11-05 10:45:25.581 UTC [42] LOG:  shutting down
postgres_1                  | .2019-11-05 10:45:25.592 UTC [40] LOG:  database system is shut down
postgres_1                  |  done
postgres_1                  | server stopped
postgres_1                  |
postgres_1                  | PostgreSQL init process complete; ready for start up.
postgres_1                  |
postgres_1                  | 2019-11-05 10:45:25.732 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 12.0 (Debian 12.0-2.pgdg100+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0, 64-bit
postgres_1                  | 2019-11-05 10:45:25.732 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
postgres_1                  | 2019-11-05 10:45:25.733 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
postgres_1                  | 2019-11-05 10:45:25.735 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
postgres_1                  | 2019-11-05 10:45:25.763 UTC [58] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2019-11-05 10:45:25 UTC
backend                     | [nodemon] starting `node express-server.js`
backend                     | check
backend                     | app is running on port 3008
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "facerecognitionbrain-api",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon express-server.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt-nodejs": "0.0.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "clarifai": "^2.9.1",
    "cors": "^2.8.4",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.3.0",
    "knex": "^0.15.2",
    "morgan": "^1.9.1",
    "pg": "^7.4.3",
    "redis": "^2.8.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^1.18.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: What's the host OS?  Why not just run `nodemon` on the host; why do you need it wrapped in a Docker container?

Comment: @DavidMaze It's windows 7 using docker toolbox and oracle virtual toolbox. I.m not sure about nodemon... i'm new to this so got to that nodemon setup from a tutorial.